# maven + jpa + hibernate + spring. too slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm doing a project with maven, jpa, spring and hibernate.
The class TopicFacadeTest takes 20 minutes o_O
Inserts and deletes are very slow.
The CPU is between 1% and 3%.
I have 6G of RAM.
What's the problem?? this is normal?
The database is initially empty.

[link Download Netbeans Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80642164/QuestionWeb/Mavenproject1.zip)

These are the configuration files:
**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="mycompanyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**test-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

<!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>                             
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mycompanyPU"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      p:database="${jpa.database}"
      p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.repository" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.service" />
```

**jdbc.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.12:3306/mydatabase
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

jpa.database = MYSQL
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
hibernate.show_sql = true
jpa.showSql = true
jpa.generateDdl = true
```

Java classes:

**Topic.java**

```
package com.mycompany.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "topic")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Topic.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT t FROM Topic t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Topic.FIND_BY_ID, query = "SELECT t FROM Topic t WHERE t.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Topic.FIND_BY_NAME, query = "SELECT t FROM Topic t WHERE t.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Topic.FIND_BY_ID_CHAR, query = "SELECT t FROM Topic t WHERE t.idChar = :idChar")})
public class Topic implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Topic.findAll";
public static final String FIND_BY_ID = "Topic.findById";
public static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "Topic.findByName";
public static final String FIND_BY_ID_CHAR = "Topic.findByIdChar";
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "idChar")
private String idChar;

public Topic() {
}

public Topic(String name, String idChar) {
    this.name = name;
    this.idChar = idChar;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getIdChar() {
    return idChar;
}

public void setIdChar(String idChar) {
    this.idChar = idChar;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Topic)) {
        return false;
    }
    Topic other = (Topic) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.mycompany.domain.Topic[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
}
```

**AbstractFacade.java**

```
 package com.mycompany.repository;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

@Transactional
public void create(T entity) {
    if (entity != null) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
}

@Transactional
public void edit(T entity) {
    if (entity != null) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
}

@Transactional
public void remove(T entity) {
    if (entity != null) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
}
```

**TopicFacade**

```
package com.mycompany.repository;

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="imports">
import com.mycompany.domain.Topic;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
//</editor-fold>

@Stateless
@Repository
public class TopicFacade extends AbstractFacade<Topic> implements TopicFacadeLocal {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public TopicFacade() {
    super(Topic.class);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public Topic findByName(String name) {
    try {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Topic.FIND_BY_NAME);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        return (Topic) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Topic> findByIdChar(String t) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Topic.FIND_BY_ID_CHAR);
    query.setParameter("idChar", t);
    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

**TopicFacadeTest.java**

```
package com.mycompany.repository;


//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="imports">
import com.mycompany.domain.Topic;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
//</editor-fold>

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-context.xml"})
public class TopicFacadeTest {

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="attributes">
@Autowired()
private TopicFacade topicFacade;
private Topic topic0;
private Topic topic1;
private Topic topic2;
private Topic topic3;
private Topic topic4;
private Topic topic5;
private Topic topic6;
private Topic topic7;
private Topic topic8;
private Topic topic9;
private List<Topic> topics;
//</editor-fold>

public TopicFacadeTest() {
}

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="testCycle">
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    topic0 = new Topic("tema0", "t");
    topic1 = new Topic("tema1", "t");
    topic2 = new Topic("tema2", "t");
    topic3 = new Topic("tema3", "t");
    topic4 = new Topic("tema4", "t");
    topic5 = new Topic("tema5", "t");
    topic6 = new Topic("tema6", "t");
    topic7 = new Topic("tema7", "t");
    topic8 = new Topic("tema8", "d");
    topic9 = new Topic("tema9", "k");

    topicFacade.create(topic0);
    topicFacade.create(topic1);
    topicFacade.create(topic2);
    topicFacade.create(topic3);
    topicFacade.create(topic4);
    topicFacade.create(topic5);
    topicFacade.create(topic6);
    topicFacade.create(topic7);
    topicFacade.create(topic8);
    topicFacade.create(topic9);

    topics = new ArrayList();
    topics.add(topic0);
    topics.add(topic1);
    topics.add(topic2);
    topics.add(topic3);
    topics.add(topic4);
    topics.add(topic5);
    topics.add(topic6);
    topics.add(topic7);
    topics.add(topic8);
    topics.add(topic9);

}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    topicFacade.remove(topic0);
    topicFacade.remove(topic1);
    topicFacade.remove(topic2);
    topicFacade.remove(topic3);
    topicFacade.remove(topic4);
    topicFacade.remove(topic5);
    topicFacade.remove(topic6);
    topicFacade.remove(topic7);
    topicFacade.remove(topic8);
    topicFacade.remove(topic9);

    topic0 = null;
    topic1 = null;
    topic2 = null;
    topic3 = null;
    topic4 = null;
    topic5 = null;
    topic6 = null;
    topic7 = null;
    topic8 = null;
    topic9 = null;

    topics = null;
}
//</editor-fold>

/**
 * Test of create method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testCreate() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("create");
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setName("tema99");
    topic.setIdChar("t");
    topicFacade.create(topic);
    assertTrue(true);
    topicFacade.remove(topic);
}

/**
 * Test of edit method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testEdit() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("edit");
    topic1.setIdChar("vf");
    topicFacade.edit(topic1);
    assertTrue(true);
    assertEquals("vf", topicFacade.find(topic1.getId()).getIdChar());
}

/**
 * Test of remove method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testRemove() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("remove");
    topicFacade.remove(topic0);
    assertEquals(null, topicFacade.find(topic0.getId()));
}

/**
 * Test of find method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testFind() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("find");
    assertEquals(topic0, topicFacade.find(topic0.getId()));
    assertNotSame(topic0, topicFacade.find(topic1.getId()));
    assertEquals(null, topicFacade.find(null));
    assertEquals(null, topicFacade.find(-747474));
}

/**
 * Test of findAll method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("findAll");
    List<Topic> topicsFindAll = topicFacade.findAll();
    assertNotNull(topicsFindAll);
    assertEquals(10, topicsFindAll.size());
}

/**
 * Test of findRange method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testFindRange() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("findRange");
    int[] range = {4, 10};
    List<Topic> topics = topicFacade.findRange(range);
    for (Topic topic : topics) {
        System.out.println(topic);
    }

}

/**
 * Test of count method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void testCount() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("count");
    assertEquals(10, topicFacade.count());
    tearDown();
    assertEquals(0, topicFacade.count());
}

/**
 * Test of findByName method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@Test
public void testFindByName() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("findByName");
    assertEquals(topic0, topicFacade.findByName("tema0"));
    assertNotSame(topic0, topicFacade.findByName("tema1"));
    assertNotSame(null, topicFacade.findByName("tema0"));
    assertEquals(null, topicFacade.findByName("jafasdg"));
}

/**
 * Test of findByIdChar method, of class TopicFacade.
 */
@Test
public void testFindByIdChar() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("findByIdChar");
    List<Topic> topicsByIdChar = topicFacade.findByIdChar("t");
    assertEquals(8, topicsByIdChar.size());
    for (Topic topic : topicsByIdChar) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s-%s", topic.getId(), topic.getIdChar()));
    }
    tearDown();
    topicsByIdChar = null;
    topicsByIdChar = topicFacade.findByIdChar("t");
    assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

**EDITED: POSSIBLE SOLUTION | datasource (connection pool), add dependency**

**test-context.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> 
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.39</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you running MySQL locally or over a network?  Slow network can kill performance.

Comment: You should try Spring's transactional unit test support as well.  No need to run the deletes yourself, it just rolls the transaction back when the test finisheds.

Comment: make a jsp and do the txns manually after the other script has made the tables

Comment: Hello!
I know about the transactional, I wanted to do it this way.
In another class also still running slow.
The database I run it in virtualbox with ubuntu, mysql.
I developed other projects with HibernateTemplate, oracle database, and performance is normal.
But in this case I'm surprised how slow it runs.

Comment: what diagnosis have you done? have you tried to check how many sqls you has submitted? how long do the SQLs take? is it the startup of application that is slow or is the logic itself running slow? Have you given enough memory to your app? etc  You should do your work first and provide enough information to other people, instead just throw out your code and saying "it is slow, why?"

Comment: Adrian, you have all the source code. 10 inserts by test method, 10 deletes by test method. "Hibernate: insert into topic (idChar, name) values (?, ?)" - "Hibernate: delete from topic where id=?". About the memory to my app, the app only have 5 classes. The memory is not the problem. I think the solution is what it says Orid. I've done my job, but did not know about the connection pool.

Answer (score 6):

For start, replace `DriverManagerDataSource` with a data source which actually pools connections. This data source just delegate to the Driver Manager to open\close a connection per transaction

Comment: Hi Orid,I changed the datasource for this one:
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

Performance has improved dramatically.
Is this the optimal solution?

Comment: Better use `tomcat-jdbc` [see configuration options](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)