# STS, Maven and Java running very slowly

Tags: java, performance, maven, ubuntu-12.04, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm running a new install of ubuntu 12.04 afer an upgrade killed my display drivers.

I've reinstalled everything but STS is running extremely slowly - it seems to hang on every mouse click and I rarely get to the stage that I can actually use it for anything.

I think this may be linked to a maven or java issue, as when I try to run a mvn package on a simple project, it takes about 20 minutes on "Building jar" and "Building war" never seems to end (I have left it for hours).

I don't know where this performance issue could be coming from - I've tried a couple of different java versions but nothing seemed to help.

I know this question is a little vague but I need help finding what question to ask to resolve this issue!

STS version 3.2.0

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Edit to add:
Another thought - could this even be an fs mounting issue? I have all my documents on a seperate ntfs partition. I don't know if that could have this effect of making read/writes very slow? Ill try creating a project on the local disk

Comment: Which edition of STS 3.2 are you using? The "based on Eclipse Juno 3.8" edition or the Juno 4.2 edition? Because when I tried the 4.2 one it had many performance bugs and the "hangs on every mouse click" experience sounds very familiar.

Comment: Eclipse Platform: Version: 3.8.1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Quite a peculiar scenario but it did end up to be the disk mounting that was making everything in my document partition run extremely slowly.

Verified the theory by copying a project to the local partition and running the mvn package command which was previously hanging. It worked immediately. so I've removed the offending lines from the /etc/fstab, rebooted and manually mounted the partition, and now it runs fine.

Comment: That's a good thing to know.  I know many devs using Linux and STS.  Although this particular problem has never come up yet, I'm sure it will one day soon.

Answer (score -1):

you should show your configuration files. What kind of project?
I have had a similar problem. Was because i was not using connection pooling. Look at this example.
[maven-jpa-hibernate-spring-too-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199876/maven-jpa-hibernate-spring-too-slow)

Comment: This is across all my projects - which are worked on my multiple developers so I don't believe this is a project specific issue.

Comment: Connection pooling is a runtime issue.